# API filter to exclude all files under parentid

Tags: google-drive-api

I want a filter for a file list call that given a folder's parent id will exclude all files as well as all sub-folders and sub-files in the entire tree.

I can use the parents option, but it still includes grand-children in the results.

```
ExcludeThis
     SubFolder
     SubFile
     SubFolder2
         SubFile2
         SubFile3
```

I can't seem to find a query that will also exclude SubFile2 & SubFile3 when I used the parentid of ExcludeThis.   I don't know the parentids for SubFolder, SubFile, SubFolder2 and don't want to have to include them (otherwise I end up making a query of every file anyway).

I'd like to be able to send the filter to Google so the results come back faster.

Comment: Checking the documentation about [Search for Files and Team Drives](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list), there is no specific way on how to exclude files in a certain folder. In that case you can use **`properties`** or **`appProperties`** which support an operator "**`has`**". Unfortunately this will check every file.

Comment: Yeah the problem I have is I want to exclude the "My Computer" from API results because it takes the Google server forever to return.  Google Backup & Sync creates these and they show up as folders.   I can't seem to easily filter because when I exclude this the grandchildren under that still show up just as having no valid parent.

Comment: I may need to grab a listing starting at <root> and then make multiple API-calls for every sub-folder found underneath instead.   It would have been nice to only need 1 API call like I could do before Google Backup & Sync created "My Computer" with thousands of files I can't easily ignore :(